# Storage - Logic/Performance - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, logic, storage

Okay, here's a standard users table;

Full Name | Birthday | E-Mail | Username | Password | Facebook | MySpace | Twitter | LinkedIn

Nothing unusual about this, it's fairly standard and text book. However, instead of multiple social networking columns for each network it could be stored like so;

Full Name | Birthday | E-Mail | Username | Password | Social

The difference being the information would be stored in the social column as an imploded array rather than in separate columns. It's quite sensible, so if there are into the thousands of users surely it would be quicker to process via script and less hit on the database.

Can anyone think of any DISADVANTAGES of using the suggested method instead of the text book method?

Comment: no bad, create a separate table  'social_affiliations'

Answer (score 0):

The two disadvantages I can think of:

1. It will be more difficult to query for social details specific to a certain user. If you knew their Facebook username was fbuser123 then you might have to query for something like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE social LIKE '%fbuser123%'`.
2. It will be slightly more difficult to use the information once it's been selected from the database, for example: Requiring that the field be `json_decode`'ed before it can be used.

Other than that, I can't think of anything else.

I would imagine that if you did this, the most efficient way of storing the data would be in TEXT format and `json_encode` the data.